# Remove substring in file using sed command

Tags: shell, unix, sed

Remove substring in a file using `sed` command in shell

Eg.

```
cat TR

SAM9001,SAM9002,SAM9005


**Output:**

9001,9002,9005
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
sed -i 's/SAM//g' TR
```

Answer (score 0):

using grep:

```
grep -o "[0-9]*" TR
```

Add `| paste -sd,` to make it comma-separated.